# Array of integers as command line argument along with other commands

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

So for my JAVA program the user has to give 6 arguments using the command line or Linux environment. One of these 6 commands is a list of numbers which I have them in the program as array of integers.

I'm not quite familiar with how it would be able to read in the list of numbers as the 6th argument ? Wouldn't the computer think of it as several arguments and not multiple numbers for one argument ? 
Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: Just specify that the list of numbers have to be the last in the arguments. That way, after reading the first 5 single arguments, you can just keep reading until the end, and you know they must be a part of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, Java will interpret multiple spaced arguments as each their own, and put each separately into the `String[] args` arguments for your `main`. However, you can still handle this by specifying that the last argument must be a list of numbers. Doing this, you can simply loop after the 5th argument, and be confident that everything you're getting should be a part of the list.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // handle first 5 args

     for (int i = 5; i < args.length; ++i) {
          // everything accessed by args[i] at this point is a part of your list
     }
}
```

You can then specify input via the `java` command

```sh
java -jar MyApp.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 int1 int2 int3 int4 int5 int6
# int1 to int6 will be read by the loop
```

Comment: Here in ur first code where you loop until args.length, doesn't this give us the length of the entire arguments together? How would it know we are referring to the 6th argument length ?

Comment: We start by referencing the index at 5 (`i = 5`), instead of 0. As such, it'll skip the first 5 elements of the array, and only work from the 6th argument and beyond.

Comment: and for the loop ++i is that intentional or it's supposed to be i++?

Comment: It's intentional, and it won't really matter. The difference between those is relatively subtle, and in this case, it won't matter at all. Feel free to use either.